# Passing multiple rows to SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, import, c#-2.0

I have a problem that I want to pass multiple rows of Excel file to a SQL Server `stored procedure` and I don't have any idea about it.
I have an Excel file to be imported, data needs to be inserted into three different tables. I have successfully imported data into one table as follows

```
string path = string.Concat((Server.MapPath("~/temp/"+FileUpload1.FileName)));
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
OleDbConnection oleCon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties = Excel 12.0;");
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]",oleCon);
OleDbDataAdapter dtap = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
oleCon.Open();
DbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string con_str = @"Data source = .;Initial Catalog=practiceDB;Integrated security=True";
SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(con_str);
bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "Excel_New";
bulkInsert.WriteToServer(rdr);
oleCon.Close();
Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles((Server.MapPath("~/temp/"))),File.Delete);
```

How to send rows to stored procedure rather than to any `DestinationTable`?

Comment: If you really wan't to do it using stored procedure is, one possible way (could be long procedure though), convert the excel data into an XML and then pass this XML as parameter to the stored procedure. Finally read from the XML to temporary tables and insert into the corresponding tables.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing the rows as parameters, how about just reading from your table `Excel_New` the in the stored procedure?